# My while loop runs infinitely, and when I check it says that the while loop has no body when I think it clearly does

Tags: java, while-loop

so I don't understand why this while loop says that it has an empty body... There is clearly a body, and it never stops running on my tests

```
public boolean Buy(int amount) {
  if (this.a>amount) {
     a = a-amount;
     x = x + (z*amount);
     while (x>=y); {
       a = a+b;
       x = x-d;
     }
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon in the while loop before the {. Should probably be

```
while (x>=y) {
```

Comment: Wow, thank you that was such a simple error... I was looking up everywhere as to how to stop my while loop infinitely running.  Still new to Java, i didn't know you could make an empty while loop with a semicolon... My tests now all pass with 100% code coverage :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your `while` loop line as pointed below specifically the `;` which makes it a empty loop or loop with empty body.

```
  while (x>=y); {
              ^...Here
```

Remove that `;` semi colon and it should rather be

```
  while (x >= y)
  {
     a = a + b;
     x = x - d;
  }
```